# python FTP download file with certain name

Tags: python

I have this FTP with folder and it contains these files:

```
pw201602042000.nc,
 pw201602042010.nc,
 pw201602042020.nc, 
 pw201602042030.nc, 
 pw201602042040.nc,
 pw201602042050.nc,
 pw201602042100.nc,
 pw201602042110.nc, 
 pw201602042120.nc, 
 pw201602042130.nc, 
 pw201602042140.nc,
 pw201602042150.nc, 
 pw201602042200.nc
```

how to download only file ending with 00?

```
from ftplib import FTP

server = FTP("ip/serveradress")
server.login("user", "password")

server.retrlines("LIST") 
server.cwd("Folder")

server.sendcmd("TYPE i") # ready for file transfer
server.retrbinary("RETR %s"%("pw201602042300.nc"), open("pw", "wb").write)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?  What do you get from `server.retrlines("LIST")`, and why don't you do anything with it?

Comment: third or fourth time that a variation of this question has been posted.

Answer (score 2):

when you obtained the list of files as `list_of_files`, just use `fnmatch` to match the file names according to wildcard:

```
list_of_files = server.retrlines("LIST")
dest_dir = "."
for name in list_of_files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name,"*00.nc"):
        with open(os.path.join(dest_dir,name), "wb") as f:
            server.retrbinary("RETR {}".format(name), f.write)
```

(note that you're writing the files on the same `"pw"` output file, I changed that, reusing the original name and provided a destination directory variable, and protecting the `open` in a `with` block to ensure file is closed when exiting the block)

Comment: the code work withour error, but the destination directory still empty, would you mind enlighten me

Comment: can you print `name` before the call to `fnmatch` ? I'm sure we'll make this work!

Comment: it said NameError: name 'name' is not define

Comment: `for name in list_of_files`: if you're using this snippet, it's just not possible.

Comment: Replacing `list_of_files = server.retrlines("LIST")` with `list_of_files = server.nlst()` would solve the problem. The issue is that `list_of_files` contains a string like "Transfer completed... xx bps", not the list of files.